# How to perform operations with row arrays using numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix of absorbance values that I've pulled from a whole wack of spectra. I call this matrix "specdt"

Each row represents the values over multiple samples at a specific wavelength. I want to find the r^2 values of the regression against a seperate array of concentration values called "Concentration."

Here's what I have so far:

```
regression = []
for row in specdt:
    x = Concentration
    y = specdt[row,:]
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
    regression.append(r_value**2)

regression_n = numpy.asarray(regression)
numpy.savetxt("r2_2.csv", regression_n, delimiter=",")
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   file "blah blah", line 42, in <module>
   y = specdt[row,:]
InexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

I suspected this is because "row" isn't an integer, so I tried to iterate over a "t" variable instead; no luck.

I suspect it's the way I'm trying to pull the row into the y values for linregress, but I can't seem to find another way to do this.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

edit: I should mention that

```
y = row
```

was the first thing i tried.

It gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ME\Downloads\Personal\Spectrometer\test\Spectrum3.py", line 42, in <module>
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_stats_mstats_common.py", line 92, in linregress
    ssxm, ssxym, ssyxm, ssym = np.cov(x, y, bias=1).flat
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2432, in cov
    X = np.vstack((X, y))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py", line 230, in vstack
    return _nx.concatenate([atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup], 0)
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

The dimensions of the conncentration array and the row should be the same.

linregress works beautifully if I pull out a single column (I transposed specdt.) This is the working code, if that helps:

```
##take only column 26 or the values for 2268; print stuff
#Absorbance2268 = spectral_data[:, 25]

#print(Absorbance2268.shape)
#print(Absorbance2268)
#
##manual entry of concentration values + array info
#conc =[0,0,0,0,0,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,8,8,8,8,8,10,10,10,10,10,4,4,4,4,4]
#Concentration = numpy.asarray(conc)
#
#print(Concentration.shape)
#print(Concentration)
#
##performing linear regression.
#x = Concentration
#y = Absorbance2268
#
#slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
#
#print "r-squared:", r_value**2
```

Comment: `spectrum(s?)` Spectra is the plural of spectrum

Comment: Haha thanks. Part 1 of 2 :P

Comment: Assuming `specdt` is a numpy array or matrix, then `row` is already the row you want (not the index of the row) so `y=specdt[row,:]` should simply be `y=row`.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I've edited to show what I've done up to that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for y in specdt:    # <---
    x = Concentration
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
```

The `for` loop gives the content of the rows themselves already. If you want the row index, use

```
for row, y in enumerate(specdt):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time Kenny. Unfortunately, this also gives the error: file "blah blah", line 230, in vstack
       return _nx.concatenate([atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup], 0)
   ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Comment: @FLAV10 please show the *full stack trace* in the question. Is "blah blah" the real file name?

Comment: @FLAV10 Looks like your `y` should be the columns, not rows?

Comment: I don't think so. Instead of pulling a specific column, I transposed the entire data set:

specdt = spectral_data.T

Am I missing something here?

Comment: @FLAV10 could you provide the shapes of `specdt` and `Concentration`?

Comment: WELLLLLLLLLLL 

that's interesting. sure enough, 41 and 42; a mismatch. 

I TRIPLE checked by counting instead of just printing the shape. I see I made a typo now. Your solution works perfectly. 

Thank you so much!!!!